# Why is the value not updating in the blazor template?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am working on a custom grid component and within each row of the Grid I have a checkbox.  The state of the checkbox will determine the css class of the row.

Index.razor:

```
<Test Items="Transactions">
    <TestBody Context="row">
        <TestCell Row=row></TestCell>
    </TestBody>
</Test>
```

Test.razor:

```
@typeparam TItem

@attribute [CascadingTypeParameter(nameof(TItem))];

<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed="true">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Rows)
            {
                <tr @key="row">
                    @TestBody(row)
                    <span>@row.Checked</span>   // .. this does not get updated
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</CascadingValue>
```

Test.razor.cs:

```
namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Test
{
    public class TestRow<TItem>
    {
        public TItem Item { get; set; } = default!;
        public int Id { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool Checked = false;
    }

    public partial class Test<TItem>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public IList<TItem> Items { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment<TestRow<TItem>> TestBody { get; set; } = default!;

        public List<TestRow<TItem>> Rows { get; set; } = new();

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                var gridRow = new TestRow<TItem>()
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Item = item,
                };
                Rows.Add(gridRow);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestCell.razor:

```
@typeparam TItem

<input type="checkbox" @onchange="eventArgs => { OnCheckChanged(eventArgs.Value); }" />


TestCell.razor.cs:
namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Test
{
    public partial class TestCell<TItem>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public TestRow<TItem> Row { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;

        public void OnCheckChanged(object checkedValue)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine((bool)checkedValue); // this reflects the correct state of the checkbox
            Row.Checked = (bool)checkedValue;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is thar when the checkbox state changes, changing the state of the row (which is passed in as a parameter into TestCell.razor) does not trigger a change in the value of row.Checked displayed in Test.razor.  Infact in TestRazor.cs it always stays false even though when inspecting the value it is correct.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You disable it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ensure-cascading-parameters-are-fixed-1

Comment: @BrianParker are you talking about disabling IsFixed?  I tried this but it made no difference. The only thing that works is calling StateHasChanged in a parent method from the child when the checkbox event in the child changes the Row data

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by passing the parent component (Test) down the TableCell compoenent as a cascading parameter and calling a parent method which calls "StateHasChanged()" when the checkbox changes in the child component:

Test.razor.cs:

```
namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Test
{
    public class TestRow<TItem>
    {
        public TItem Item { get; set; } = default!;
        public int Id { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool Checked = false;
    }

    public partial class Test<TItem>
    {
        //....

        public void Refresh()
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }    
    }
}
```

TestCell.razor.cs:

```
namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Test
{
    public partial class TestCell<TItem>
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        public Test<TItem> Owner { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public TestRow<TItem> Row { get; set; } = default!;

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;

        public void OnCheckChanged(object checkedValue)
        {
            Row.Checked = (bool)checkedValue;
            Owner.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```